# JS копирование текста без сохранения стилей

Tags: javascript

Есть общеизсвестная проблема, что если что-то копировать из браузера и попытаться вставить в тот же ворд, то в ворд переносятся стили(бэкграунд, шрифт, цвет и т.д.)

Пока есть рабочее решение для хрома, мозилы, яндекса. Но оно не совсем корректно работает в ИЕ, там убираются пробелы между строками, что не очень правильно и конечному пользователю придется расставлять переносы в ручную, если он скорпиует много текста

```
  const onCopy = ev => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const textSelection = document.getSelection().toString();
    const clipboardData = ev.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    clipboardData.setData('text', textSelection);
  };
```

Может кто сталкивался с кроссбраузерным решением данной проблемы?

Comment: У меня проблем нет копируеш в блокнот потом делай шо хощ

Comment: Проблем в принципе нет, все тексты что на сайт что с сайта необходимо копировать через блокнот, чтоб лишних пробелов не было, переносов, правильная разметка. Размечать на сайте нужно через админку, так же и в ворде

Comment: Вроде вопрос задан корректно, а находится умники, которым лишь бы что-то написать...